# Matrix of boolean values in an Access form

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, vba

I am designing a form at work where I need to be able to set "Properties" for a large number of (accounting) "structures". I have a "Value" field where the user enters the value that property must take and then I have 1 column for every structure where the user must be able to check / uncheck each property for each structure. Also, I need to be able to suggest checkbox values (aka mapping of properties to structures) to the user so that he/she doesn't have to manually click all the checkboxes that will always need to be ticked. Finally, the number of properties (rows) and the number of structures (columns) should not be assumed to be fixed though I don't want the user to be able to modify it himself. I just want it so that a dev (probably me) doesn't have a hard time adding or removing structures.

For now I have used a local table where each structure is a column and I have hardcoded my properties (which is good). However, I am not sure that using a local table is good design. We normally avoid having forms and tables in the same Access DB to separate forms and data. Also, I'm wondering if there is an elegant solution that I am missing. There will be at least 10-15 structures and 11 properties, that would make 110 (11*10) checkboxes to handle so I cannot do it manually (i.e. create 110 checkboxes and check 110 values everytime...).

Here you can see what that part of the form looks like for now.

[image]

I know this will be a chattier question but I really need a design check on this so here are a few questions that I try to make as general and objective as possible:

- In Access, how is it possible to create a matrix of controls where 1 column contains a fixed (but changeable by a dev) number of properties, a "value" field that can take text and then 10+ columns with Yes/No values ?

  - Is it possible to do it without a local table ?

VBA is perfectly admissible.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

> In Access, how is it possible to create a matrix of controls where 1 column contains a fixed (but changeable by a dev) number of properties, a "value" field that can take text and then 10+ columns with Yes/No values ?

I've never seen any VBA code that does what you describe. VB6 allowed the creation of "control arrays" to logically group controls (and work around some limitations on the number of controls on a form), but I've never seen that mentioned for VBA.

> Is it possible to do it without a local table?

Is it *possible*? Maybe, since you can modify a form via code by opening it in Design View and using `CreateControl()` to add controls.

Is it *practical*? Probably not, because the "Access Specifications" section of Access Help mentions the following limit...

"Number of controls and sections that you can add over the lifetime of the form or report: 754"

..so it sounds like code that repeatedly modifies a form could very well break after a while.

My recommendation would be to create a temporary table, use it, and then discard it. If you're worried about front-end bloat then you could create the temporary table in a temporary .accdb file and then link to it.

Comment: Yes, I'm afraid that there is no way around this. For the time being, I have made a "template" local table and I create another table at runtime using the username which feeds the subform. It's not pretty but it fits my needs for now.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe I'm missing something, but it seems pretty easy to me.

Make each structure a record.
Then in another table, make each property a record with a 1-many relationship with the structure table. So, each structure will have many properties.

Then a form based on the structure with a sub-form based on it's properties.

Default property values can be set in the table structure.

And of course the tables can be linked from another DB.

Comment: That would be too hard to work with. I really need to be able to have all the structures and all the properties as easy to manage as possible. If the user has to open many forms and navigate through records they will hate it because it's not very practical.

Comment: @AlexandreP.Levasseur, if they have to do all the mods on one form, then they'll have to have one control for each mod they can perform.  The alternative to having so many controls, as you know, is to put related details on a separate form.

Answer (score 1):

> In Access, how is it possible to create a matrix of controls where 1 column contains a fixed (but changeable by a dev) number of properties, a "value" field that can take text and then 10+ columns with Yes/No values?

I'm still not certain why you want multiple bits/booleans in a single column, but you might be able to utilize bit logic and long integer column.  VBA does something like this with its constants.  For instance, in a MsgBox, you make your type = `vbCritical + vbYesNo`.  Its result is in an integer value that VBA interprets to make a Critcal MsgBox with only a Yes and a No button.  The reason this works is because the value of each constant is so distinct that any summation with like constants results in a unique value that can be de-parsed.  It's fairly elegant from a user perspective, but I'd hate to do the math on the back-end to make such a function work.

It might be better to maintain a separate table of available properties and/or property sets and build / maintain your property sheet that way.  You could assign property sets as well as individual properties to particular controls.  You could also specify in either table whether there is a default value for that property and/or what that value is.

It is also likely that you do not need that many bits.  I'd be happy to narrow my answer to your situation if you could update your question with more detail regarding the nature of your bit need(s).

> Is it possible to do it without a local table?

You might be able to create a `DAO.Recordset` dynamically in Access.

It might be better to adjust your properties table(s) (see above) to be a permanent table in one of your databases rather than re-populating the same data every time.

Comment: Some properties have limited (2-3) possible values but about half of them have values that are not limited to a particular set. The reason for so many "bit fields" is that depending on the account on which the analyst is working it may or may not fit into a structure. The default values provide the most common values but in the end the analyst is the judge of which structure has to contain which property. As for the vbCritical + vbYesNo, it's a matter of checking bits. If vbCritical is 3 and vbYesNo is 1 that makes binary 11. You can check each property using bitwise AND operator.

Answer (score 1):

You could take more of a master/detail approach, combining your bit fields into a string description describing the boxes which are checked.

For example, if you have a structure named 'structure1', value 100, and 5 condition bits set, you could have one string column with text 'cond1, cond2, cond7, cond8, cond9' and then another button allowing them to modify that set of conditions for that single structure.

You'd have fewer checkboxes, anyways.

The only thing I can think of equivalent to '`a matrix of controls where 1 column contains a fixed (but changeable by a dev) number of properties`' is an editable query result set.

You'll need a table for your structure -> default conditions set, if nothing else, but it doesn't have to be in the same db as the front end.

HTH

Comment: The string description would be too hard to use for the users. It has to be idiot proof and manipulating strings would not fit that criteria.

Comment: no, they wouldn't manipulate them, the string would be read-only.  it would be built by your process to concatenate the list of checked items.  To modify the contents of the string, they'd have to go to a detail form with one checkbox for each condition for that structure only, not all the structures they can set bits for.